# Notebook vs spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm very new to PySpark.

I am running a script (mainly creating a tfidf and predicting 9 categorical columns with it) in Jupyter Notebook. It is taking some 5 mins when manually executing all cells. When running the same script from spark-submit it is taking some 45 mins. What is happening?

Also the same thing happens (the excess time) if I run the code using python from terminal.

I am also setting the configuration in the script as

`conf = SparkConf().set('spark.executor.memory', '45G').set('spark.driver.memory', '80G').set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '20G')`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set driver memory from spark-submit arguments.

Comment: @hamzatuna, won't it work setting it inside the script by passing `sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)`?

Comment: @hamzatuna, and also it is taking excess time if I run it using `python script.py`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: driver memory cant be set after application start. you need to submit it with `spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 60G script.py` and you shoud initlize SparkConf() because it will override arguments.

Comment: @hamzatuna thanks for pointing this out. Do I need to set executor and maxResult sizes as arguments too or they can be done via script? And can you explain what you mean by `shoud initlize SparkConf() because it will override arguments.` ?

Comment: i think it can be set from arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways to run your Spark code like you have mentioned few Notebook, Pyspark and Spark-submit.

1. Regarding Jupyter Notebook or pyspark shell.

While you are running your code in Jupyter notebook or pyspark shell it might have set some default values for executor memory, driver memory, executor cores etc.

2. Regarding spark-submit.

However, when you use Spark-submit these values could be different by default. So the best way would be to pass these values as flags while submitting the pyspark application using "spark-submit" utility.

3. Regarding the configuration object which you have created can pe be passes while creating the Spark Context (sc).

> sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: Sorry for accepting the answer late. I was still confused and wanted to have some hands-on. But things seem clearer now. Thanks for your help in both the questions. 
Just an add-on, can you add some technical views on how spark-submit differs from running it on spark-shell?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but to initialize my spark variable I was using this line :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
```

The problem is that "local[X]", is equivalent to say that spark will do the operations on the local machine, on X cores. So you have to optimize X with the number of cores available on your machine.

To use it with a yarn cluster, you have to put "yarn".

There is many others possibilities listed here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html